# Azure Notification Hubs with Android - Sending notifications to subsets of users

Tags: c#, android, azure, notifications, azure-notificationhub

I am currently building an Android messaging app and I am trying to send notifications to all users who are part of a group. I have an Azure Notification Hub set up which is working fine for sending a notification to all devices that are registered, but I cannot seem to get it working for just a subset of all user ie a group.

The devices register with Azure and with GCM on startup.

I have tried using "Tags" to try send a notification to an individual but I am not sure if I am doing it right... I must not be because it isn't working!

In the following code I am trying to send a notification to an individual by using their username as a Tag...

This is the code in my service to send a notification:

```
    // POST api/notification
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody]Notification notification)
    {
        var notificationToSave = new Notification
        {
            NotificationGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            TimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow,
            Message = notification.Message,
            SenderName = notification.SenderName
        };

        var recipientNames = await GetRecipientNamesFromNotificationHub();

        var recipientNamesString = CreateCustomRecipientNamesString(recipientNames);

        string notificationJsonPayload =
            "{\"data\" : " +
            "   {" +
            "   \"message\": \"" + notificationToSave.Message + "\"," +
            "   \"senderName\": \"" + notificationToSave.SenderName + "\"," +
            "   \"recipientNames\": \"" + recipientNamesString + "\"" +
            "   }" +
            "}";

        var result = await _hubClient.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync(notificationJsonPayload, "ken@test.com"); // If this second parameter is omitted then a notification is sent to all registered devices.

        notificationToSave.TrackingId = result.TrackingId;
        notificationToSave.Recipients = recipientNames;

        await Session.StoreAsync(notificationToSave);

        return Ok(notificationToSave);
    }
```

And this is how I am registering a device on the Android side:

```
private void sendRegistrationIdToBackend(String registrationId) {

        String backendBaseUrl = "http://myurl.net/";
        if (backendBaseUrl == null || backendBaseUrl == "")
        {
            return;
        }

        PushNotificationClient client = new PushNotificationClient(backendBaseUrl);

        Device device = createDevice(registrationId);

        client.registerDevice(device, new Callback<Device>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Device device, Response response) {
                //writeStringToSharedPreferences(SettingsActivity.SETTINGS_KEY_DEVICEGUID, device.DeviceGuid);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Device successfully registered with backend, DeviceGUID=" + device.DeviceGuid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Backend registration error:" + retrofitError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        Log.i(TAG, registrationId);
    }

    private Device createDevice(String registrationId) {
        Device device = new Device();
        device.Platform = "Android";
        device.Token = registrationId;
        device.UserName = LogInActivity.loggedInUser;
        device.DeviceGuid = null;
        //todo set device.PlatformDescription based on Android version
        device.SubscriptionCategories = new ArrayList<>();
        device.SubscriptionCategories.add("ken@test.com"); // This should be adding this username as a Tag which is referenced in the service.... Not sure if this is how I should do it!
        return device;
    }
```

This is how I registering a device:

```
 private async Task<RegistrationDescription> RegisterDeviceWithNotificationHub(Device device)
    {
        var hubTags = new HashSet<string>()
            .Add("user", new[] { device.UserName })
            .Add("category", device.SubscriptionCategories);

        var hubRegistrationId = device.HubRegistrationId ?? "0";//null or empty string as query input throws exception
        var hubRegistration = await _hubClient.GetRegistrationAsync<RegistrationDescription>(hubRegistrationId);
        if (hubRegistration != null)
        {
            hubRegistration.Tags = hubTags;
            await _hubClient.UpdateRegistrationAsync(hubRegistration);
        }
        else
        {
            hubRegistration = await _hubClient.CreateGcmNativeRegistrationAsync(device.Token, hubTags);
        }
        return hubRegistration;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

good evening.
You should try check your registrations by using Visual studio 2015.
Install it, connect azure, azure hubs, registred devices. And try send your test message on test token (+check "does your registration exist on notification hub").

Comment: I have checked this and have sent test notifications but it still only works with a broadcast.. It says that I have 0 tags registered, however. I am not sure how to register tags..?

Comment: when you register on notification hub you pass 2 params: 1) deviceToken, 2) tokens.
After that new record created on notification hub with new regId and expiration date.


https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530747.aspx (create registration)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.servicebus.notifications.windowsregistrationdescription.aspx (set up tags)

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me! How do I modify this line of code `var result = await _hubClient.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync(notificationJsonPayload);`if I want to include the tag "ken@test.com" ?   I have tried inserting it as a tag when registering the device and referencing it when posting the notification but that is not working

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.servicebus.notifications.notificationhubclient.sendgcmnativenotificationasync.aspx
You should add tags on register. And use them when you try to sen some notification.
So. Lets try some test ode? Something like

            List<string> tags = new List<string>();
           tags.Add("testTag");
          hubRegistration = await _hubClient.CreateGcmNativeRegistrationAsync(device.Token, tags);
 await _hubClient.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync("{\"data\" : {\"message\": \"testMessage\"} }", "testTag");

Comment: Thank you Sergey I have it working now! Appreciate your help

Comment: Nice)) Good evening.